# JSSOR Left Navigation not working but Right is

Tags: jssor

We can click the arrow on the right to slide but can't click the arrow on the left, swipe left and right does work.

http://uat.syndacast.com/novotelkolkata/library/

I compared the settings to the demo slider but nothing seems different.

http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html

Quite possibly a css problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the left arrow is gone when mouse down, so the 'click' event would not fire.
I noticed that you added the following css,

```
.jssora05l {  left: 128px; }
```

Please add css for mouse down as well,

```
.jssora05ldn {  left: 128px; }
```

Comment: awesome that worked! But now the right arrow is moved to the edge and cut in half however after resize it does position correctly. The strange thing is I do call the resize function when the page loads so why would this happen?

Comment: The gallery also appears to be showing 1 pixel of the next slide? Thanks

Comment: There is no 1 pixel gap. That's the way chrome scales. Btw, I see you Set size of 'slides' container to 840 x 470, It should be better if you set it to original size of image 1280 x 800;

Comment: With jquery version, it will keep not initialized as raw html until document ready. You may see the look of raw html before initialization of jssor slider.

Comment: Yes that's what is happening I believe the page has not complety rendered and looks strange sometimes, even though I am using document.ready, I had to put a timeout in there to call resize() as I noticed it would called it before the page finished loading. So you're saying I need to update my jquery verison?

Comment: jQuery always recommends to execute js after document ready. But if you use jssor slider no jquery version, it will initialize immediately.

Comment: I am using document.ready already but it's like resize() is being called before the page has finished loading sometimes not all the time. I even have to call it like this one page load setTimeout(function(){ ScaleSlider(); }, 500); but even then it still has problems, I keep increasing the time, why would resize() not wait for the document to be completely loaded?

Comment: I worked out what's happening if you CTRL+F5 on the page it need to load more elements hence the page is taking longer, you will see the gallery gets cut in on the right side, so it's like the page didn't finish loading, if you just F5 it works http://uat.syndacast.com/novotelplatinum/library/

Comment: I just realized that JSSOR is not scaling in proportion, I set the gallery container to 1280 x 800 as you suggested but that didn't. I believe because it's calculating based on the original dimensions every time not the current dimensions of the container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69579/discussion-between-user2760338-and-jssor).